# Calculate Upper Quartile of Grouped Data

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

Problem :

If I have a table of numerical data

$$ \begin{matrix} Value &  Freq \\
40-49 & 7 \\
50-59 & 6 \\
60-69 & 10 \\
70-79 & 8 \\
80-89 & 9 \\
Total & 40
\end{matrix}  $$
How do I calculate the upper quartile of this *grouped* data?

---

I have seen a resource that says that the $Q_{3}$ is calculated as below.

$0.75 \cdot 40 = 30$

so the upper quartile should be in class $70-79$.

$$ Q_{3} = (70-0.5) + (79-70+1) \cdot \left( \frac{8-10}{(8-10) + (8-9)} \right) \approx 75...$$

But the multiple choices differ. What is the correct method? thanks.

Comment: There is no consensus on how to calculate percentiles, including quartiles, in the literature. Usually, when this is used, a definition is given.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel This problem is from highschool test sample. Is there an elementary formula that is used regularly in school? because as  I remembered there must be one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several different methods, but I suspect the one you are quoting from starts with

\begin{matrix} Value &  Freq & Cum.Freq\\
40-49 & 7 & 7\\
50-59 & 6 & 13\\
60-69 & 10 & 23\\
70-79 & 8 & 31\\
80-89 & 9 & 40\\
Total & 40
\end{matrix}

and might suggest

$$Q_{3} = (70-0.5) + (79+0.5-(70-0.5)) \cdot \frac{ 30 - 23}{31 - 23} \approx 78.25$$

Similar methods might be slightly different in detail, e.g. ignoring the $\pm 0.5$ or using $30.5$ instead of $30$, but they should all give an answer near $78$